# Transform a string in another string, by replacing characters, depending of the number of words in the string

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

If I have any string, like:

'arest   alpha gma beta' or 'alpha '

I want to:

- to add a star after each keyword
- if there are multiple words to replace the space `between` them with `||`

No I'm using:

```
term_str = " ".join(keyword.strip().split()).replace(' ', '* ||')
```

The problem is that if is just one keyword, the * is not added.

I know I can write a `for loop` and a `condition`, but I'm looking for something more python one line expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the string, add the `*` after each word, then join the modified words together with `||`:

```
def func(keywords):
    return '||'.join(map('{}*'.format, keywords.split()))

print(func('arest alpha gma beta'))  # arest*||alpha*||gma*||beta*
print(func('alpha '))  # alpha*
```

Comment: Subjective I guess, but I think a comprehension would be more readable than the `map()`.